# Prove that $p + q = 2 \implies p = q = 1$ using number theory

Tags: number-theory, natural-numbers

> If $p, q \in \mathbb{N}=\{1,2,3,\ldots\}$ and $p + q = 2$, then $p = q = 1$.

How do I prove this using the basic properties of Natural Numbers? I could see how exceeding simple it is to solve, but proving something so basic and fundamental involves deep meta-thinking.

Comment: This is quite hard to help with without knowing the framework. Russel and Whitehead, for example, take *pages* to prove that 1 + 1 = 2.

Comment: You should also know that some people think $0 \in \Bbb N$ and some do not. Number theory generally does not, while set theory does, so for this problem I would assume not. I think it is worth specifying every time it matters. Here the conclusion is false if $0 \in \Bbb N$.  [Peano arithmetic](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Peano_axioms) assumes $0 \in \Bbb N$

Comment: The title of the question is so general that no one can even predict what you wanted to ask. Please change it.

Comment: @ArmanMalekzadeh Well it's just one click away.

Answer (score 4):

Here is one such proof:

Let $p,q\in \mathbb{N}$. That means, by definition, that $p\geq 1$ and $q\geq 1$.
Now, suppose that $p+q=2$. We know that $p+q>p$, since natural numbers are positive, so we have
$$2=p+q>p\geq 1$$
That is $2> p\geq 1$, since the only natural number that satisfy the last equality is $1$, then $p=1$. Same argument shows that $q=1$.

Comment: What you posted is right for sure, but I really think OP would like a proof with Peano Axioms, or even with set theory.

Answer (score 2):

What exactly do you mean?

Since this question seems that simple and almost selfevident,are you looking 
for a particular proof or derivation from a formal axiomatic system for natural
numbers like set theoretic construction of the natural numbers or Peano Axioms?
And what is considered natural numbers here?

The propostion makes only sense if 0 is not included.
Otherwise $p=0$ and $q=2$ or $p=2$ and $q=0$ would satisfie the proposition too

The straigthforward way to do it then would just be:
$p+q=2$ implies that both p and q are lesser equal $2$(since p,q>0).

So p,q (since natural numbers) must lie in the set $\{1,2\}$

Then consider the binary sum operation on $\{1,2\}$ 
$$(+):\{1,2\}^2\longrightarrow N,\ (+)(n,m):=n+m$$ 
The values which $(+)$ takes for the finite number of
pairs in $\{1,2\}^2$ are, $$(+)(1,1)=2;\ (+)(2,1)=(+)(1,2)=3;\ (+)(2,2)=4$$

Hence out of all possible pairs in$\{0,1\}^2$ only $(1,1)$ is an preimage of 2 under this operation.
q.e.d.

Comment: I am pretty sure OP wanted a proof with very basic settings, i.e., Peano Axioms, definition of addition and ordering by successors.